# Importing PayPal (or any other script) from URL inside component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal

I have component named CallToAction and I would like to import PayPal, use their button and activate it with the script but I am not exactly sure how to properly import script from URL inside Vue component (I don't want to have it global on every page, only import it on pages that render CallToAction component).

I have tried following but I am unable to access variables from that script even though I can see it in html.

```js
<template>
    <div class="paypal-button" id="paypal-plan-container"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted: function() {
        let paypalScript = document.createElement('script')
        paypalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&vault=true')
        document.head.appendChild(paypalScript)
        paypal.Buttons({
            createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'sb'
            });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID);
            }
        }).render('#paypal-plan-container');
    }
}
</script>
```

Gives this error `ReferenceError: paypal is not defined`

Comment: you'll need to wait for the script to load

Comment: How? I am familiar with async operations in javascript but can’t find any example that suits my case.

Comment: `paypalScript.onload = function() { ... do the paypal thing here ...}` - I'd put that line just *before* `document.head.appendChild(paypalScript)`

Comment: Will try that tomorrow, looks promising.

Comment: @Bravo I have used Omar's fully working example but you were right, it needed some event listener that would fire when script is loaded. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the component I used

```
<template>
  <div ref="paypal"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      order: {
        description: "Buy thing",
        amount: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: 1000
        }
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const ClientID = "";
    script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${ClientID}`;
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
  methods: {
    setLoaded: function() {
      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [this.order]
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            // ajax request
          },
          onError: err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        })
        .render(this.$refs.paypal);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So I was missing event listener and accessing paypal variable through window. It works flawlessly now.

Comment: It worked for me after a small modification. The  "addEventListener" needed a callback, so that would be:
`script.addEventListener("load", () => {
this.setLoaded
});`

Answer (score 0):

When a script expects to be included directly in the page, it's probably worth looking for a vue wrapper to take care of the issue of loading it via a vue component. Is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paypal-checkout) what you need?

Comment: I have found this before but it looks like it doesn’t subscriptions product that I have already created on PayPal.